# Create Input fields with IronPython in a text area in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Is it possible to create Input fields with an IronPython script? If so, does anyone have any sample code they can share?

Context: I want to create a table in a text area, with input fields in the table cells. I can create the required document properties via a script but am now trying to figure out how to create the fields themselves.

Comment: Can you just always have the input fields created in the table and just show/hide the `div` they are in with python?

Comment: I think Mark's solution is the way to go. I'm not sure it's possible to create a Property Control programatically. I wasn't able to find any method in the API docs about this, at least. if you have a TIBCO Support contract, I suggest to submit a ticket so Spotfire Engineering can provide a definitive answer.